# unwind and group for the nested array objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb, I have the data structure like this:

```
{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "car" : [ 
                {
                    "model" : "aaa",
                }, 
                {
                    "model" : "bbb",
                }, 
                {
                    "model" : "ccc",
                }
            ],
            "user" : {
                "id" : "123"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

And I want to group and count the car model field. So first I tried the unwind method like this:

```
.aggregate([
  { $project: {"data.car.model":1, "data.user.id":1} },
  { $unwind: {
      path: "$data.car",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      } },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$data.car.model",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
      } }
])
```

But the result is:

```
{
    "_id" : [ ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] ],
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

which is not what I wanted since the model didn't unwind. The result I'm hoping is:

```
[{_id:"aaa",count:1}, {_id:"bbb",count:1}, {_id:"ccc", count:1}]
```

Then by looked at
[mongodb unwind array nested inside an array of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168698/mongodb-unwind-array-nested-inside-an-array-of-documents), I tried the $project the nested array:

```
.aggregate([
  { $project: {"car":"$data.car.model", "user":"$data.user.id"} },
])
```

But the result is:

```
{
    "car" : [ ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] ],
    "user" : ["123"]
}
```

As you can see, the car and user was embedded in an array, which I still can't apply the $unwind method. However, I hope it should be like:

```
{
    "car" : ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"],
    "user" : "123"
}
```

The mongo I'm using is 3.2, I searched a lot on the web but didn't find the answer. Is there possible to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) **"each"** array independently:

```
.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$data", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$data.car", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$data.car.model",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

You cannot actually "reach into" and [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as you attempted. So you first "un-wrap" the outer array, and then the "inner" one. Then the documents are flattened for grouping.

An alternate approach may be to use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to "flatten the array" before "unwinding":

```
.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$data.car",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$data.model",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

But it would not really be recommended since the "projection" more likely involves a higher cost than that incurred by using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for each level of nesting in the array.

Comment: Better and clean solution. +1 (y)